# Query for custom posts with a specific tag slug

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, tags

I've got a wordpress site with several custom post types. On a page, I want to display only posts of a custom type that have a specific tag. I've been using the following query to do so:

```
$args = array(
    'tag_slug__in'    => array('tag1', 'tag2'),
    'post_type'       => 'custom_post',
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'  => 10,
    'order'           => 'ASC',
    'orderby'         => 'menu_order'
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

However, when I run this query, I get both the page I have tagged like this, and a different custom post type (event) with the tags. However, I should have this limited to the stated custom_post type. I've double checked that the name I provided matches the name of the custom post type.

Obviously, I could trivially filter this myself at the start of the loop to only display my custom post type, but I want to properly handle returning no results. Is there a way to have the query properly filter my results to JUST posts with both this custom type and the listed tag(s)?

Comment: What is `echo $posts->request;` ?

Comment: Weird, I just pulled that and got this:
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM 
    wp_posts LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = 
    wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( 
    wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (16) ) AND 
    wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'event', 
    'custom_post', 'custom_post2') AND 
    ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
    ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC LIMIT 0, 10`

Why would it be suddenly changing my filtered post types to all post types?

Comment: Could be a plugin/theme that is changing the query.

Answer (score 5):

Since `tag` is a taxonomy of a `custom_post` post type, the query could look like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'custom_post',
    'tax_query'  => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'post_tag',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     =>  array(
                'tag1',
                'tag2',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);

$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

See WP_Query [Taxonomy Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters).

Comment: This is wrong. A tag is not with tax_query. It should be possible with "tag_slug__in". If not you have done something wrong ....

Comment: Built-in WordPress tags are not associated with custom post types by default and are assigned to regular posts only. The question was about a specially registered taxonomy for the custom post type.